# How can I get my media keys working in i3 + gnome?

Tags: linux, gnome, arch-linux, i3-window-manager

I'm using the i3 window manager along with GNOME. Everything seems to work except for my media keys--volume up, volume down, brightness up, brightness down, etc. How can I get them to work in the GNOME way? I know I map these keys to certain commands in my i3 config, but GNOME is supposed to handle these things, and also give a nice visual feedback bar for the volume and brightness levels. How can I get media keys to work again? I'm on Arch linux, btw, running GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if you still want an anwser.
Haven't tested with GNOME, but i use this in my i3config
From: [Avalanche of sheep](http://joaquinlp.me/blog/your-guide-to-a-damn-light-arch-linux-with-i3-and-text-apps/)

```
# Multimedia Keys
# increase volume
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec amixer -q set Master 5%+ unmute
# decrease volume
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec amixer -q set Master 5%- unmute
# mute volume
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec amixer -q set Master mute
# pause / play / next / previous
bindsym XF86AudioPlay exec playerctl play-pause
bindsym XF86AudioNext exec playerctl next
bindsym XF86AudioPrev exec playerctl previous
```